# How to show previous_post_link () / next_post_link () in shortcode - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this shortcode (I wrote it in functions.php) that shows the read previous and read next links in a single post:

```
    <?php
    function prev_next_buttons_post() {

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="container-single-post-buttons">';
            $html .= '<div class="prev-next-buttons">' . previous_post_link('%link', '<  read previous') . '</div>';
            $html .= '<a href="/blog" class="btn-btd-black">back to blog</a>';
            $html .= '<div class="prev-next-buttons">' . next_post_link('%link', 'read next >') . '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
    }
    add_shortcode('prev_next_buttons', 'prev_next_buttons_post');
```

The problem I have is that when I add the shortcode:

```
<section>
    <div class="container btd-container-sm">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[prev_next_buttons]') ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

when inspecting it shows the different structure and the links are outside their containers losing their styles:

[image]

I need them to be in the same structure as defined in my shortcode.
How could I solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` do not *return* a value, but write to the output buffer directly.

You need to use their counterparts that *return* the value, so that you can then concatenate those into your string - `get_previous_post_link` and `get_next_post_link`.

(If you check the source code for the former two functions, you’ll see that they are just wrapper functions that call the latter two, and `echo` their return values - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/#source)